# How do I save and reuse Microsoft Office themes?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I've created a bunch of Heading styles, colours, fonts, etc. that I would like to reuse in all my documents and those of my colleagues. I used the page layout tab and saved the theme to a .thmx file. When opening a new document however, I didn't see the new theme. One way or the other I've managed to get it to show up under Page Layout > Themes > Themes.

Here's the problem(s):

1. Creating a new document and then clicking on my theme under Page Layout > Themes some of the formatting takes place, but most of my heading fonts/sizes/etc don't take effect. It's almost as though it wasn't saved as part of the theme.
2. Any custom styles I created weren't saved as part of the them
3. If I get this right (the theme that is) how do I distribute it so that it's available on everyone's machines in the office?

***This is the correct format:***

[image]

***This is the format after I've saved my theme and try to reuse it (incorrect):***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/apply-customize-and-save-a-document-theme-in-word-or-excel-HA010354866.aspx) website should be very helpful.

### Saving a theme

1. On the **Page Layout** tab, in the **Themes** group, click **Themes**.

[image: The **Themes** group on the **Page Layout** tab in Excel 2010]

2. Click **Save Current Theme**.
3. In the **File Name** box, type an appropriate name for the theme, and then click **Save**.

The custom document theme is saved in the Document Themes folder and is automatically added to the list of available custom themes.

### Applying a theme

To change the document theme that is applied by default in Word, select another predefined document theme or a custom document theme. Document themes that you apply affect the styles (A combination of formatting characteristics, such as font, font size, and indentation, that you name and store as a set. When you apply a style, all of the formatting instructions in that style are applied at one time) that you can use in your document.

1. On the **Page Layout** tab, in the **Themes** group, click **Themes**.

[image: The **Themes** group on the **Page Layout** tab in Excel 2010]

2. Do one of the following:

   - To apply a predefined document theme, under **Built-In**, click the document theme that you want to use.
   - To apply a custom document theme, under **Custom**, click the document theme that you want to use.

   `Note`    Custom is available only if you created one or more custom document themes. For more information about creating custom document themes, see Microsofts' [Customize a document theme](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/apply-customize-and-save-a-document-theme-in-word-or-excel-HA010354866.aspx#BM2).
3. If a theme that you want to use is not listed, click **Browse for Themes** to find it on your computer or network.

Comment: Thanks wizlog, I've seen this page before and followed much of it, but I still don't seem to be able to get my fonts to save to the template. The most obvious of which is the Headings fonts and one custom style that I created called Important

Comment: Have you tried taking note of where you saved the theme, then browsing for that theme?

Comment: Yeah sure have. I can see it under Page Layout > Themes. Here's what I do to test: I create a new word document, type in a title, sub-title, headings 1 through 3. I highlight each line and apply the correct style to each. Then I head over to Page Layout > Themes and chose my custom theme. The fonts and colours change from the standard Office theme, but they certainly don't appear like the theme I saved. I just tried resaving the theme as well from a previous document that does look right and retried the test, but it still didn't work?

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the difference between the two? Additionally, ensure that the changes your making are considered "[themes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/what-is-a-theme-HA010338417.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010338409)", and can be saved.

Comment: I just edited my post and added some images.